# Multiple Widgets with Configuration Activity

Tags: android, android-widget

The problem: App widget that launches some config screen when added, and then, when pressed, implements some action, also based on the info input on the config screen. AND allowing multiple instances of the widget, each with its own config.
Bugs I went through while implementing many examples:

1. Clicking the widget would always take me to the config activity
2. Clicking a widget would update all of the widgets
3. Clicking would do nothing at all
4. Adding a widget would not update the widget info until another widget was added/reboot/re-launch project on Eclipse

Comment: Great work. Unless I misunderstood, it is recommended to list the problems you had in the question section then create an answer to your own question with the solution you found and accept that answer, which would mark the question as closed. It would also make it more readable for future readers, I think.

Comment: Agreed. Please read [the site documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for learning more about setting up FAQ-style questions here.

Comment: OK guys.. will work on that. Just felt so happy I managed to sort it out that I felt I had to give something back to the community which I get so much from...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. If you are copying as example - remember to change all instances of package names (Eclipse will help out).

There might be simpler/better ways of doing this but mine works and has ALL THE INFO. I left all my miserable comments inside the code because of the pain involved in getting this to work... and to the best of my knowledge - leaving anything out will just kill one of the features listed in my question above.
Cheers,
Nir

First - manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ntasher.afcon"
 android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ntasher.afcon.SettingsPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget Updates -->
    <receiver
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name="com.ntasher.afcon.MyAppWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetprovider" />
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Now - layouts - activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_tv"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_tv"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and widget_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Widget Text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

widgetprovider.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="72dip"
android:minHeight="72dip"
android:updatePeriodMillis="100000"
android:configure="com.ntasher.afcon.SettingsPage"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_main"/>
```

Classes::
SettingsPage.java (the main activity):

```
package com.ntasher.afcon;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SettingsPage extends Activity {

int thisWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "WIDGET_CONFIGURED";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE = "WIDGET_UPDATED";
SharedPreferences customSharedPreference;
EditText ed = null;
Button save = null;
TextView widgetId = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    widgetId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_tv);

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //updateWidget();
            if (ed.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                saveToPreferences("Widget" + thisWidgetId, ed.getText()
                        .toString().trim());

                updateWidget(thisWidgetId);

                setResultDataToWidget(RESULT_OK);
            } else
                setResultDataToWidget(RESULT_CANCELED);
        }
    });

    getIdOfCurrentWidget(savedInstanceState);

}

/** Get the Id of Current Widget from the intent of the Widget **/
void getIdOfCurrentWidget(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        thisWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        if (getWidgetData("Widget" + thisWidgetId) != null) {
            save.setText("Update");
            ed.append(getWidgetData("Widget" + thisWidgetId));
        }

        widgetId.setText("Widget ID = " + thisWidgetId);
    }

    // If they gave us an intent without the widget id, just bail.
    if (thisWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
        finish();
    }

}

/**
 * Update the Current Widget - This is very important to ensure the widget
 * is enabled
 **/
void updateWidget(int thisWidgetId) {
    //Intent clickIntent=new Intent();
    /*Intent clickIntent = getIntent();
    //clickIntent.setClass(getBaseContext(), MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
    clickIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, ed.getText().toString()
            .trim());
    clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, thisWidgetId);
    //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
      //      0, clickIntent, 0);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            thisWidgetId, clickIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingIntent);
    // update this widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidgetId, remoteViews);*/
    Intent updateIntent=new Intent(this, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
    updateIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    updateIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("abcdef" + "://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(thisWidgetId)));
    //updateIntent.setClass(getBaseContext(), MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
    updateIntent.putExtra("ID",thisWidgetId);
    sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this,"upd Widget", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

void setResultDataToWidget(int result) {
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, thisWidgetId);
    setResult(result, resultValue);
    finish();
}

@SuppressLint("WorldWriteableFiles")
public void saveToPreferences(String file_name, String data) {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data",
            MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(file_name, data);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}

@SuppressLint("WorldReadableFiles")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getWidgetData(String file_name) {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Data",
            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    return (myPrefs.getString(file_name, null));
}
```

}

And finally MyAppWidgetPRovider.java

```
package com.ntasher.afcon;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
Log.i("onUpdate", "AAA");
Toast.makeText(context,"OnUpdate", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget_main);
      // Set the text - from saved sharedpreferences
     String widgetText=getWidgetData(context,"Widget" + widgetId);  
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, widgetText+String.valueOf(widgetId));

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);

//*****THE FOLLOWING IS A MUST!!!
//if no intent.setData to something very specific, the intents for each     widget are UNIFIED into one intent and
//this intent will be the original intent with no ID at all
//************************************
      intent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("abc" + "://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(widgetId)));
//************************************

      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds); //<<<<CHECK IF NEEDED
      intent.putExtra("ID",widgetId);// <<this is used by the onReceive to identify the widget pressed

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, 0);

      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }


    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}

/*
 * This is called when an instance the App Widget is created for the first
 * time.
 */
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    Log.i("onEnabled", "AAA");

}

/*
 * This is called for every broadcast and before each of the above callback
 * methods.
 */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int thisWidgetId=intent.getIntExtra("ID", -1);
    String widgetText=getWidgetData(context,"Widget" + thisWidgetId);
        Toast.makeText(context,"onReceive:"+Integer.toString(thisWidgetId)+widgetText, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

/*the following is required for showing the right name when adding the widget otherwise the name will be null*/
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            if (widgetId==thisWidgetId)
            {
                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                      R.layout.widget_main);
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, widgetText+String.valueOf(thisWidgetId));
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidgetId, remoteViews);

            }
        }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Log.i("onReceive", "AAA");

}

/*
 * This is called When all instances of App Widget is deleted from the App
 * Widget host.
 */
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Unschedule any timers and tasks
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

/*
 * This is called every time an App Widget is deleted from the App Widget
 * host.
 */
@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // Unschedule any timers and tasks
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}
public String getWidgetData(Context context, String file_name) {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Data",Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    return (myPrefs.getString(file_name, null));
}


}
```